# A RenderFlex overflowed by 18 pixels on the bottom

Tags: aplicação-web, flutter

Estou criando uma aplicação Web em Flutter através do código abaixo:

```
import 'package:clean_architecture_course/utils/color_pallet.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: ColorPallet.appbarColor,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 10,
            child: Container(
              color: ColorPallet.userLoginBar,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 90,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Container(
                      color: ColorPallet.sidMenuBar,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //Icons
                          IconButton(
                              onPressed: (){},
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.search,
                                size: 20,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 90,
                      child: Container(
                        color: ColorPallet.mainBoard,
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

O que ocorre é que ao redimensionar minha página Web ao mínimo possível, ocorre esse erro que é causado devido ao IconButton. Já tentei com diferentes Widgets (Expanded, FittedBox etc..) porém o erro continua. Preciso que o ícone seja redimensionado junto com a página de forma a não ocorrer esse erro.

Abaixo exibo uma imagem do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acrescenta um singlechildscroolview no body e deixa a sua coluna como filho dele. Assim vai criar uma rolagem na página para a parte que ultrapassa os limites

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não está claro sobre o que você quer exatamente, a estrutura do body do seu Scaffold tá confusa. Deixei assim e não aconteceu erro algum (testei no dartpad):

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 52,
        color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue.shade900,
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: (){},
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Não precisa usar `Expanded` no `AppBar`, ele já ocupa a tela toda (na largura).

## Expanded

O flex do `Expanded` (e outros flex widgets) é por fator e não porcentagem.

```
Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 300,
  color: Colors.grey,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: []
  )
)
```

[image: Container vazio]

Temos um container 100 de altura e 300 de largura com um `Row` vazio. Este `Row` vai ocupar a largura toda (`mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max`).

Agora, vou adicionar dois widgets de tamanho fixo dentro do `Row`: um vermelho, de 100 pixels, e outro verde, de 50 pixels.

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      color: Colors.red
    ),
    Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.green
    ),
  ]
)
```

[image: Metade do container ocupado.]

Agora, resta apenas 150 pixels de espaço livre, certo?! É neste valor que `Expanded` irá trabalhar. Vou adicionar estes dois ao `Row`:

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
    color: Colors.yellow
  ),
),
Expanded(
  flex: 2,
  child: Container(
    height: 100,
    color: Colors.purple
  ),
),
```

Eu não especifiquei o flex do container amarelo (o padrão é 1). Do roxo, eu coloquei 2. Quanto é 150 (espaço livre) dividido por 3? 50. O fator flex do roxinho é 2, portanto, ele vai ocupar 100 pixels (2 * 50). O amarelo vai ficar com o restante, no caso, 50 pixels.

[image: Roxinho maior.]

E se eu alterar o flex do amarelo pra 3 (mantendo o roxo em 2)? Bem, 150 / 5 = 30. O amarelo teria 90 pixels e o roxo, 60.

[image: Amarelo ficou maior.]

E se houver apenas um `Expanded`? Ele iria ocupar todo o espaço restante disponível, independente do fator flex.